# Define a function using pattern matching and repeated replacement to sum the elements of a list.(exercise in Paul Wellin's Book)

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, replacement

I am reading Paul Wellin "Essentials of Programming in Mathematica".

I have a question about his answer to 4.1 Exercise 5.

4.1 Exercise 5:

> Define a function using pattern matching and repeated replacement to sum the elements of a list.

His answer is here:

```
sumList[lis_]:=First[lis//.{x_, y___} -> x + {y}]
```

I cannot understand why this function works correctly.

My wrong guess how his function works is here:

```
sumList[{1, 2, 3}]
=>
1 + {2, 3} 
=>
1 + 2 + {3}
=>
1 + 2 + 3 + {}
=>
6 + {}
=>
{}
```

By the way,

```
sumList[lis_]:=First[lis/.{x_, y___} -> x + {y}]
```

also works correctly.

Comment: Two things: note that `x + {y}` is automatically evaluated to `{x + y}`, and that `x + y` is internally represented as `Plus[x, y]`.

Comment: Thank you again, J. M. is computer-less. But 0 + {} was evaluated to {}, not to {0} by Mathematica.

Comment: That sounds about right. `Listable` functions applied to `{}` will always yield `{}`, as there are no elements to map to.

Comment: Thank you very much, J. M. is computer-less. Maybe I understand thanks to you. But why did Wellin write " repeated replacement" instead of "replacement"?

Comment: I guess he wanted the user to use `//.` somewhere in the solution.

Comment: Thank you very much!